# How do I solve a "No such Calendar" error with Evolution and Google Calendar?

Tags: evolution, google-calendar

I am using a google calendar with evolution for quite a while now. I was never having any troubles. Just recently, I suppose just after an update, whenever I want to create a new event in evolution (for the just mentioned google calendar) I get the err message "No such calendar". When I dismiss changes an re-open evolution the entry has been added anyway.

This is somewhat annoying. I googled, but haven't found anything yet which suggests that it not problem many people have!? Looking for help, maybe someone here knows an answer!

- I have tried removing and readding the calendar

Comment: Did you try removing and readding the calendar?

Comment: jep I did, didn't do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I had this too, open ubuntu software center and search for evolution.
There will be 2 results with the envelope icon. 1 is installed, the other isn't, install that one.

It's a kind of a bad answer, but it works.